# How to pass multiple parameters in an open doc URL for a webi report in repository?

Tags: business-objects, opendocument

I want to pass multiple parameters like year, month, week, etc., to a webi report in repository.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I recall it is just a matter of constructing your URL query string in standard fashion, e.g.

```
[URL_path]?paramA=123&paramB=xyz
```

As when forming any URL, you will need to make sure you URLEncode your parameters.

Here's a link to a BO XI 31 guide to opendoc syntax: [Viewing Documents Using OpenDocument](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31SP3/en/xi31_sp3_opendocument_en.pdf).

The BO API lets you query each "prompt" for its "type", e.g. single valued (lsM) or multi-valued. You may need to include parameter types in the URLs you build. The BO documentation explains this.

When passing date information, you may encounter localization issues depending on how your reports are set up and how you create your session with BO.

Comment: thnx for the response..but i already tried the url format that you give [URL_path]?paramA=123&paramB=xyz.. but it is not working..

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is - it works if you get the syntax right.

Comment: Actually, this *used to work* with BO 3.x, but in BO 4.x, everything has changed.  Even after following the updated BO OpenDocument documentation, I can't get this to work anymore....

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you an example from my side:

```
https://URL_path/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&sType=wid&sRefresh=Y&iDocID=AUcrjvCCPOVHtSvXJV9Qs0k&lsMYBO_BU=A;B&lsSYBO_CALYEAR=201410&lsSYBO_CRNCY=EUR
```

where:

`sIDType=CUID` --> I will provide the `CUID` of the WebI report

`&sType=wid` --> type is `WEBI-Report`

`&sRefresh=Y` --> the report should be refreshed = `yes`

`&iDocID=AUcrjvCCPOVxxxvXJV9Qs0k` --> this is the `CUID` of the report

`&lsMYBO_BU=A;B` --> this is a `M` (Multiple value variable) called `YBO_BU`, and I am giving the values `A` and `B`

`&lsSYBO_CALYEAR=201410` --> this is a `S` (Single value variable) called `YBO_CALYEAR`, and I am giving the value `201410` (format might be important if you have users with different date formats, so use YYYYMM)

`&lsSYBO_CRNCY=EUR` --> this is a `S` (Single value variable) called `YBO_CRNCY`, and I am giving the value `EUR`

I hope it helps.

BR,

Belén.